# What's the meaning of "scar on the first cut"?

Tags: meaning

It's a chapter header in Rework book written by Jason Fried.
Here is a summary: 
Don't scar on the first cut. Don't create a policy because one person did something wrong once. Policies are only meant for situations that come up over and over again."

Comment: In this case, _Don't create a policy because one person did something wrong once._ Fried explains this unusual expression himself (thankfully). How idiomatic it is is another matter; '_Don't give a knee-jerk reaction_ is more common but perhaps less stylish. The trouble is, I'm not sure how sensible the attempted metaphor is. Scarring is involuntary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But in the other sentence he says: The second something goes wrong, the natural tendency is to create a policy." So here what does second mean? Does it mean 'the second time'?

Comment: ... Pardon!!!??? Just try replacing 'second' here with 'minute', and then tell me 'second' here means 'second time'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's a bit confusing. Here the second may mean 'second time'. But if it means so, it kinda contradicts the context of the article.

Another meaning which I interpret is that 'the second' shows the instance of the action. That means,

As soon as someone does something wrong, the natural tendency is to create a policy.

Comment: @HamedGhaderi - yes, given the context 'second' refers to the moment something goes wrong as Edwin suggests.

Comment: If you look at the original, 'The second something goes wrong, the natural tendency is to create a policy.' is the first sentence after the title. 'Second' as an ordering marker or ordering adjective needs an antecedent.

Comment: You must have seen me trying to ride a horse.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is given in your summary of the chapter:

> Don't create a policy because one person did something wrong
>   once.Policies are only meant for situations that come up over and over
>   again.

Perhaps you meant to ask "Why does Jason Fried think unnecessary policies are like scar tissue"?

Not having read the book, I would suggest it is because as concisely described on [http://activerecoveryboston.com](http://activerecoveryboston.com/injury-information-center/general-concepts/scar-tissue/)

> Scar tissue binds up and ties down tissues that need to move freely.

In terms of a business, time and energy can be tied up in complying with unnecessary policies set up to prevent a one-off situation from occurring again and this prevents the business from operating effectively.

Comment: As I mentioned above there is another sentence in this chapter which says "The second something goes wrong, the natural tendency is to create a policy." What does "second" mean here? Does it mean the second time?

Comment: It is "sort of" referring to the unit of time. ie.one-sixtieth of a minute. It is not actually meant to be taken literally, but rather to mean " As soon as".  BTW You added your comment after I had submitted my answer.

Comment: I'm confused. Can above sentence change the meaning of the title? If not, so what does the second means here?

Comment: You need to check the answers to your questions JUST before you add a comment as you are getting out of step with the replies. It is not referring to a second cut.

Comment: I'm new here. So I'm sorry

Comment: No need to be sorry, we were all new once (and for me it was only  6 weeks ago.)  I am just offering a suggestion that helps with the flow of comments, but which I sometimes still forget myself.

Comment: Excellent explanation of what I now think is a cracking new metaphor. The 'hidebinding' effect (don't quote me: dodgy string and mixed metaphor) on tissues _that need to move freely_ is of course key here. How did you arrive at this quote? I'd never thought of the disadvantages of scarring.